# Replace all repeated occurrences of string for the single same

Tags: php, regex, replace

How replace all repeated occurrences of string for the single same:

I have string like:

```
1-string-2-string-3-string-55-otherstring-66-otherstring
```

I need replace for:

```
1-2-3-string-55-66-otherstring
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$str = '1-string-2-string-3-string-55-otherstring-66-otherstring';
print_r(implode('-', array_reverse(array_unique(array_reverse(explode('-', $str))))));
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/MvAnl)

Or using Regular Expressions:

```
(\w++)-?(?=.*\b\1\b)
```

Breakdown:

- `(\w++)` Match and capture a word
- `-?` Match following hyphen if any
- `(?=` Start of positive lookahead

  - `.*\b\1\b` Recent captured word should repeat
- `)` End of lookahead

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/KQ3i5E/1)

PHP code:

```
echo preg_replace('~(\w++)-?(?=.*\b\1\b)~', '', $str);
```

Comment: tks for atention dude, perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_word_count to get words and array_count values to count how much time each word is meeting in string

and replace each word when the count is greater than 1

```
<?php
$text = "1-string-2-string-3-string-55-otherstring-66-otherstring";

$words = str_word_count($text, 1); 

$frequency = array_count_values($words);

foreach($frequency as $item=>$count) {
$item = rtrim($item,"-");

    if($count >1){
        $text = str_replace($item,"",$text);
    }
}
echo $text;
?>
```